# hardware_id on Branch.io for Android appears to _not_ be ADID, what is it?

Tags: android, webhooks, branch.io, android-identifiers

On a branch.io webhook from android devices I am getting a value for hardware_id that appears to be a 64 bit number rather than a UUID format ADID as I understand they should be formatted.  [Documentation](https://dev.branch.io/getting-started/webhooks/advanced/#sample-post-body-for-all--event--install-open-custom-webhooks) indicates it is Android ID (adid?)

```
hardware_id: 'IDFA' (iOS) | 'Android ID' (Android),
```

But I appear to be getting hardware_id from android os platform events on the webhook that are 64 bit numbers rather than uuids and that don't match android id when retrieved directly from the operating system in my app.  Am I misunderstanding what this field is?  Have others used this field successfully on a webhook to correlate user activity or is there a better field in branch.io?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the Android ID is normally the 64bit android device identifier.  Solved this by recording that value elsewhere rather than by trying to adjust or understand what information branch was sending.